# Coordinates Format

Tags: coordinates

42 SXC 965214 452136

Will someone please tell me what kind of coordinates are the above? How distance can be derived from the above coordinates? I urgently need it.

Answer (score 5):

Might be [MGRS](http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/library/policy/army/fm/3-25-26/ch4.htm#par4).